# Is it possible to return a function that depends on the value of a Maybe type

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a simple typeclass that kind of mimics ducktyped True/False determination

```
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool

instance YesNo Int where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True

instance YesNo Bool where
    yesno = id
```

Is it possible to have it upon encountering a maybe type to check if the type within the maybe implements the yesno typeclass (if it is an int or a bool) and then return True or False based on that?

Something along the lines of

```
instance (YesNo a) => YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesno (Just _) = yesno _
    yesno Nothing = False
```

It feels like the answer is no as it would possibly defeat the purpose of strong types but can someone explain a bit as the concepts are still a bit murky to me.

Comment: I recommend [`{-# Language InstanceSigs #-}`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html?highlight=xinstancesig#extension-InstanceSigs) at the top of your file. Add signatures to your methods: `yesno :: Int -> Bool` and `yesno :: Bool -> Bool` and finally `yesno :: Maybe a -> Bool`.

Comment: You can replace that last method by [`yesno = maybe False yesno`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just replace `_` with some variable name like `x`.

```
instance (YesNo a) => YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesno (Just x) = yesno x
    yesno Nothing = False
```

> It feels like the answer is no as it would possibly defeat the purpose of strong types but can someone explain a bit as the concepts are still a bit murky to me.

The instance definition just says, `Maybe a` is an instance of `YesNo` if `a` is an instance of `YesNo`.

When you call `yesno` on `Maybe a`, the function at the *call site* must know that `a` is a `YesNo` instance. For example, you *can’t* do this:

```
f :: a -> Bool
f a = yesno (Just a) -- error
```

You would need to know that `a` is `YesNo` inside `f` so you can “pass it along” to `yesno`…

```
f :: YesNo a => a -> Bool
f a = yesno (Just a) -- ok
```